# Azure Functions - Node vs .Net Performance - ColdStart

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I don't know whether it is purposefully done or Azure is poor by performance than AWS. Whenever I cold-start an Azure Function it takes close to a minute.

The same function cold starts less than a second (close to 250 msecs) with AWS.

What I see is, Azure stores all the function code in Azure Storage account and load it over the network creating this latency. This is with consumption plan.

If I use App Service Plan for functions, so junky to even have that in modern applications. It can reduce to 3 seconds but not even close to what AWS performs.

What are the other way I can improve performance with Azure, so that I can cold start my functions quickly?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a member of the Azure Functions team. I can assure you we're not deliberately making JavaScript slow. It just comes with some challenges we're still working through.

As you noted, the 60 second cold start performance you are getting is due to the network latency incurred when loading a very large number of small files which is typical for node.js applications.

Our current recommendation is for your to take advantage of [Azure-Functions-Pack](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack). It uses webpack to dramatically decrease the number of files loaded by your application.

We are working on some improvements designed to make the manual process of running Functions Pack unnecessary. We aim to have some of these improvements in production sometime later in 2017.

Comment: You have functions in four different forms and nothing works good. Deployment of Functions in tons of ways, nothing works with scale. On the other side, there is one and only way to upload code to AWS and one way to execute the code and just works. Working with functions required lot of research and at the end of the day makes me feel waste of company time and my personal time. With the first impression, every Developer / Architect loose confidence on the platform to work with, since things does not work as such mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Does Implementing in .Net improves performance? or Problem with all the languages? Which language will have improved performance with Azure Functions App?

Comment: I did with functions pack, webpack and still performance is not in par with AWS or for a production system. One more issue with packing is, if there is any issue, it will always complain on line 1, which is hard to figure it out.